# Is XAMPP still there?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost, wampserver

I installed XAMPP for Windows on my Win7 PC, but now I decided to uninstall it & replace it with WampServer (It's more comfortable for me to enable/disable features in PHP) but, even though I uninstalled XAMPP & installed WampServer, when I open any localhost folder or alias, I see the XAMPP favicon in the tab, what makes me think it's not uninstalled properly.
What can you tell me about it?.

Thank you.
Marcelo.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your browser cache

Comment: Whilst this is almost certainly correct, it would make a much better answer if you explained it, eg this is likely down to your browser caching the favicon. Clearing the browser cache should fix this

Comment: Thanks Quver!
Hahaha. After I sent this question I thought about that!! I'm so stupid!! Sorry folks. Problem solved.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is the best ;)
No problem, Marcelo

Comment: Well, I've solved that, but now I've got another problem: I can access alias directories (after lots of tries I finally could but can't remember which one was the correct solution) but I don't see the icons in folders without index.html & in the one with the index included, the CSS is not loaded, so the site is a mess!!.

Comment: Dont use Alais's. Create a Virtual Host for each of your projects. [Heres how to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)